# Sed remove selected line to file using shell script variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have shell script variable `var="7,8,9"`
    These are the line number use to delete to file using sed.

Here I tried:
    `sed -i "$var"'d' test_file.txt`

But i got error `sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: ,'

Is there any other way to remove the line?

Comment: Did you just write your variable like that because you thought it'd be useful, or is it the output of another command? It may be more convenient to have the list of numbers in a different format.

Comment: No i am just write my way. So you can use your way

Answer (score 1):

`sed` command doesn't accept comma delimited line numbers.

You can use this `awk` command that uses a bit if BASH string manipulation to form a regex with the given comma separated line numbers:

```
awk -v var="^(${var//,/|})$" 'NR !~ var' test_file.txt
```

This will set awk variable `var` as this regex:

```
^(7|8|9)$
```

And then condition `NR !~ var` ensures that we print only those lines that don't match above regex.

For inline editing, if you `gnu-awk` with version `> 4.0` then use:

```
awk -i inplace -v var="^(${var//,/|})$" 'NR !~ var' test_file.txt
```

Or for older awk use:

```
awk -v var="^(${var//,/|})$" 'NR !~ var' test_file.txt > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp test_file.txt
```

Comment: That will delete specific line numbers only due to use of anchors around the `(` and `)`

Answer (score 0):

I like sed, you were close to it. You just need to split each line number into a separate command. How about this:

```
sed -e "$(echo 1,3,4 | tr ',' '\n' | while read N; do printf '%dd;' $N; done)"
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
sed -i "`echo $var|sed 's/,/d;/g'`d;" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider would be `ed`, with `printf '%s\n'` to put commands onto separate lines:

```
lines=( 9 8 7 )
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]/%/d}" w | ed -s file
```

The array `lines` contains the line numbers to be deleted; it's **important** to put these in **descending order**! The expansion `${lines[@]/%/d}` adds a `d` (delete) command to each line number and `w` writes to the file at the end. You can change this to `,p` instead, to check the output before overwriting your file.

As an aside, for this example, you could also just use `7,9` as a single entry in the array.